# how to sort 3 arrays together in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays: **A, B,** and **C**:

```
char A[6][10];
int B[6];
int C[6];
```

I want the above 3 arrays (which have the same n# of elements) to be sorted simultaneously . If i sort array **B** from lowest to highest value then i want arrays **A** and **C** to follow **B's** pattern. this maybe better explaines with an example below.

I have a code below attempting this, **my question is how can i edit/fix my code to do this function of simulataneous sorting which is described below?**

**Unsorted List:**

```
A[6]              B[6]          C[6]      
John               12           2
David              30           1
Michael            12           2
Steve              12           1
Sam                19           2
Claire             12           1
```

I then want to sort **B[i]** from **lowest to highest**, while **A[i]** & **C[i]** are sorted according to **B[i]**

```
A[6]              B[6]          C[6]      
John               12           2
Michael            12           2
Steve              12           1
Claire             12           1
Sam                19           2
David              30           1
```

Then if there are identical/same numbers in **B[i]**, then i want to sort **C[i]** from **lowest to highest** causing **A[i]** and **B[i]** to be sorted according to **C[i]:**

```
A[6]              B[6]          C[6]      
Steve              12           1
Claire             12           1
John               12           2
Michael            12           2
Sam                19           2
David              30           1
```

Then if 2 names from **A[i]** have similarities in **B[i]** and **C[i]**, then sort **A[i]** in alphabetical order.

```
A[6]              B[6]          C[6]   
Claire             12           1   
Steve              12           1
John               12           2
Michael            12           2
Sam                19           2
David              30           1
```

I wrote a code to try to do this but i am having a bit of a struggle at causing 1 array to sort simulatanuosly to another array.
**Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong or describe a better/best way to do this type of sorting?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

char A[6][10]={"John","David","Michael","Steve","Sam","Claire"};
int B[6] = {12,30,12,12,19,12};
int C[6] = {2,1,2,1,2,1}; 
int i=0;
int true=1;


for (i=0;i<6;i++)
{
printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);
}

while(1)
    {
        true = 0;

        for (i=0;i<6;i++){

            if(B[i]> B[i+1]){
                int temp = B[i];
                B[i] = B[i+1];
                B[i+1] = temp;
                C[i]= C[i+1];
                swapped = 1;
            }

        }
        if (true==0){
            break;
        }
    }

printf("\nnew list\n");

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);
        }


}
```

Output of code:

```
John    12      2
David   30      1
Michael 12      2
Steve   12      1
Sam     19      2
Claire  12      1

new list
John    12      2
David   12      2
Michael 12      1
Steve   12      1
Sam     19      1
Claire  30      1
```

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you swapping elements of `A` and `C` the same way as for `B` (although swapping `A` will require string copying instead of simple assignment)?

Comment: I suspect the best solution here might be a single array of structs.

Comment: An array of structs with qsort would be much better, but it wouldn't take much to fix the bubble sort either.

Comment: A could be an array of pointers-to-char (string), then swap would not require copy

Comment: @ooga and dmitri, would the array of structs be fine with re-ordering strings? ill give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to replace the index(or pointer) rather than to replace each element in such a case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isDes(int x, int y, char A[][10], int B[], int C[]){
    return B[x]>B[y] || 
       B[x]==B[y]  && (C[x]>C[y] || C[x]==C[y] && strcmp(A[x], A[y])>0);
}

int main(){
    char A[6][10]={"John","David","Michael","Steve","Sam","Claire"};
    int B[6] = {12,30,12,12,19,12};
    int C[6] = {2,1,2,1,2,1};
    int index[6] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5};//prepare an array of index
    int i=0;
    bool swapped;

    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);
    }

    while(1){
        swapped = false;

        for (i=0; i<6-1;i++){//i<6 : bad because when i==5 , X[i+1] is out-of-range access
            if(isDes(index[i], index[i+1], A, B, C)){ //check needs to be replaced.
                int temp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[i+1];
                index[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped==false){
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\nnew list\n\n");

    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[index[i]],B[index[i]],C[index[i]]);//indirect reference by index
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed a comment at `A, B, C)){ //check need`. Fixed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, I was missing. I thank you for pointing out the fix.

Comment: Don't thank me, thank BLUEPIXY. He wrote the code -- all I did was tidy up a comment :)

Answer (score 5):

All the other answers are correct in pointing out that you did not swap A and C correctly.  But I will try to answer the question "what is the best way" instead.  Ideally, since your A, B and C arrays are all related to each other, you should be using an array of structs instead of 3 separate arrays.  I don't know if you have learned about structs yet, but here is an example of how I would rewrite your code using structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Person {
    char name[10];
    int  age;
    int  group;
} Person;

#define DIM(a)              (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

main()
{
    Person people[] = {
        { "John",    12, 2 },
        { "David",   30, 1 },
        { "Michael", 12, 2 },
        { "Steve",   12, 1 },
        { "Sam",     19, 2 },
        { "Claire",  12, 1 }
    };
    int i=0;
    int n=0;

    for (i=0;i<DIM(people);i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].age, people[i].group);

    // Here I used a bubble sort since it seemed like what you were doing.
    n = DIM(people)-1;
    while (1) {
        bool swapped = false;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if (people[i].age > people[i+1].age) {
                Person temp = people[i];
                people[i]   = people[i+1];
                people[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        n--;
        if (!swapped)
            break;
    }

    printf("\nnew list\n");

    for (i=0;i<DIM(people);i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", people[i].name, people[i].age, people[i].group);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simple sorting function like an insertion sort. Basically you want to base all your comparisons in the sorting function on the array that you want others to be sorted along with.

In this case the comparisons will be made for B. The only remaining part is to do the exact same swaps to A and C that you did with B.

Look at the code below, it will print the output that you want in the first step. The remaining steps follow the same idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sortarray(long size, char A[][10], int B[], int C[])
{
    long i;
    long j;
    char Atemp[10];
    int Btemp;
    int Ctemp;
    for(i=1; i<size; ++i) {
        j=i;
        while(j>0 && B[j-1] > B[j]) {

            Btemp = B[j-1];
            B[j-1] = B[j];
            B[j] = Btemp;

//----> Swap the C and A elements the same way you swapped B

            Ctemp = C[j-1];
            C[j-1] = C[j];
            C[j] = Ctemp;

            strcpy(Atemp, A[j-1]);
            strcpy(A[j-1], A[j]);
            strcpy(A[j], Atemp);

//----> Swapping of C and A is done

            j = j-1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    char A[6][10] = {"John", "David", "Michael", "Steve", "Sam", "Claire"};
    int B[6] = {12, 30, 12, 12, 19, 12};
    int C[6] = {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
       printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);

    printf("\n");

    sortarray(6, A, B, C);

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",A[i],B[i],C[i]);
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

Started with:

```
John    12  2
David   30  1
Michael 12  2
Steve   12  1
Sam     19  2
Claire  12  1
```

After sort:

```
John    12  2
Michael 12  2
Steve   12  1
Claire  12  1
Sam     19  2
David   30  1
```