# How to sort separate arrays together (similar to sorting a table by one column)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Given two or more arrays, how can I choose to sort one array and sort the others accordingly? This is similar to sorting a table by one column.

```
int main()
{
    int values1[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    double values2[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    std::string values3[] = {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"};

    // sort by values1

    // values1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    // values2 = {5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0};
    // values3 = {"o", "l", "l", "e", "h"};

    // sort by values3

    // values1 = {4, 5, 3, 2, 1};
    // values2 = {2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    // values3 = {"e", "h", "l", "l", "o"};
}
```

Below are some strategies I came up with. I hope you can give me some hints into the right direction. Thank you!

Strategy 1:

1. Make a struct `struct sortstruct{int i; double d; std::string s};`
2. Create vector and copy values inside
3. Write a predicate function and use std::sort
4. Copy values back into original structure.

This seems to be quite easy but also this involves duplicating all data twice and also creates a lot of small objects if the arrays are large. Also, this is not flexible if the number of arrays varies.

Strategy 2:

1. Make a copy of the array to sort with.
2. Sort the copy using std::sort.
3. Move through the sorted copy and for each value, find the value in the original array, then swap the index positions in all value arrays.

Also quite easy to implement, but finding the value in the unsorted array takes quadratic time (linear time for each value).

Strategy 3:

1. Implement a custom sorting algorithm which takes a "key" array and applies all swaps to the other arrays.

I don't like that I have to do the sorting by myself. But this is of course no problem if this is the best strategy.

Comment: How does strategy 1 involve duplication of data?

Comment: @CinCout: See steps 2 and 4.

Comment: If the three array are related to each other, why not wrap them it a class, so hide the implementation detail.

Comment: Option 4: create a fourth array of indexes and reorder that array according to whatever array is being used as the key. Minimal swapping, no copies, and no chance of breaking the logical linkage between the rows, but adds an extra layer to subsequent look-ups (`values1[indexes[i]]`) and not going to work with `std::sort`.

Comment: @Fabian You can create a vector of structs and keep inserting struct objects in the vector, and then call the predicated sort() and finally access the sorted vector. Where is the duplication?

Comment: @CinCout: I assume that you want to replace the arrays with a vector of structs. Then of course, there is no duplication. But my application requires the data to be in separate arrays at the beginning and end, so you have to pay for the conversion from arrays to vector and from vector to arrays.

Comment: Found a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695133/how-to-sort-3-arrays-together-in-c

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be probably to create a struct that contains the values or use a `std::tuple`, put instances of it in a vector and sort the latter, thus getting rid of all the other arrays.

If you can't do that, you can introduce one layer of indirection that is an *array of indices* (actually a *lookup array*).
Order it according with your policy and never change the positions of the items in the other arrays. Whenever you want to get the i-th tuple of elements, get the i-th element from the array of indices and use it to get the right values from all the other arrays.
You won't have problem if you add more and more arrays in the future, as long as you create them implicitly ordered somehow each in respect to the other.
When you add a new tuple, simply push at the end of the array of indices the *size* of the other arrays (I assume all of them have the same size): that will be the index of the new elements. Then sort again the array of indices if needed.
Sort function probably requires you to pass a comparison function that has access to the outer arrays, but that's quite simple to do with lambdas and capture by reference.

Comment: I like the idea of the lookup array. However, this implies that the arrays belong together forever, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @Fabian Well, it reduces to a minimum the number of copies and swaps. That cannot be for free. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would suggest to use data structures that tie together the tuples spread over individual arrays, like a `struct` or a `tuple`.

But one could make use of the fact that a sorting algorithm like `qsort` uses a custom comparison function to decide whether to swap two values or not.
Given that, one could define a comparison function that, besides returning the result of the comparison, has side effects in the sense of "manually" swapping values in other arrays.

I know that it is ugly, as it relies on the internals of sorting algorithm `qsort`, and I am not completely sure if I miss something essential (and I will not cry if somebody downvotes the answer for that reason). But maybe it can be a help in very exceptional cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int values1[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
double values2[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
std::string values3[] = {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"};

int cmpfunc( const void *a, const void *b) {
    // calculate the array indexes of a and b using pointer arithmetics:
    size_t indexA = ((int*)a - values1);  
    size_t indexB = ((int*)b - values1);
    int result = *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
    if (result > 0) {
        swap(values2[indexA],values2[indexB]);
        swap(values3[indexA],values3[indexB]);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    qsort(values1, 5, (size_t) sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Your idea seems to go into the direction of my strategy 3. You are right, this is a bit ugly, but if you encapsulate this properly, it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
ranges::sort(ranges::view::zip(values1, values2, values3),
             std::less<>{},
             [](const auto& t) { return std::get<1>(t);}); // Projection
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29ac51c61af61aac)